# postgresql: Can you run a query as a specified role, in pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

If you have admin or root access yourself, is it possible to:

1. set some variables via `set_config()`, then
2. run a query **as a specified role**, in pgAdmin, to see what the result is for that specific role?

eg *temporarily* do something like:

```
select set_config('mytokenvar', 123, true);
select * from foo.bar as role registered_user;
```

and then see whether it works for that role or not, and then have the settings and role cleared from the session?

Am using pgAdmin 4.4.17

Comment: You can run  `set role ...` before you execute the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that worked!! Thanks! :-D